# Accessing undefined variable outside of method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why this code works, I think it should give an error but it doesn't:

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       
   def greeting(self):
       # Should return "hi, my name is " followed by the name of the Person.
       return "hi, my name is "+self.name
   
   def __str__(self):
       return "str"

some_person = Person("foo") 
print(print(some_person.greeting()))
```

In the `__init__` method, I try to access a variable that is not actually defined (shouldn't be an error?)
and in the `greeting` method, I try to access that variable which is just defined in `__init__` (shouldn't it be an error?). It doesn't give any error and works smoothly? how is that possible?

Comment: `print(print(some_person.greeting()))` should print None because this is what is returned from the inner `print` call.

Comment: Why do you feel there should be any error? In `__init__` you are defining a new **attribute** (`self.name`) from an **existing** function argument (`name`). This code is perfectly fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldnt be an error! That's because self is the Object it**self** (you see why its called `self`?) so if you define something in the `__init__` function, it is stored inside the *object* so you can use it from another function by peeling it off the object itself. The `name` variable you were talking about is defined in the function definition! Where you put `__init__(self,`**name**`)`

Comment: Thanks, buddy I understood it. I came from java, which something like that is absolutely wrong(I treated self like "this" in java), but it's quite clear now.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def __init__(self, name):
       self.name =name
```

In fact, you tried to access a variable that is actually defined. `name` is defined in function parameter.